# Response Stream from HttpWebRequest lifetime scope

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebrequest

I have this method:

```
public Stream Load(string term)
{
    var url = CreateSearchUrl(term);

    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

    return new GZipStream(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress);
}
```

As you can see, I return the stream back to the caller but I'm not sure if this is safe in terms of the WebRequest gets disposed by the runtime and thus invalidating my returned stream.

I could convert it to a byte array and return a MemoryStream or even use a WebClient but I just don't like this idea =).

Thanks!

Comment: The runtime will not dispose it. The only issue you have is the connection with the server wont be closed until you dispose it.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an easy way to safely return the Stream without having resource leaks.  The main issue is disposing the WebResponse:

```
public Stream Load(string term)
{
    var url = CreateSearchUrl(term);

    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse(); // whoops this doesn't get disposed!

    return new GZipStream(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress);
}
```

Closing the WebResponse is actually more important than closing the response stream, since closing the WebResponse implicitly closes the response stream.

The only way I know of getting the WebResponse to be disposed with the Stream would be to implement a decorator around the GZipStream that disposed of the WebResponse (as well as the GZipStream) when it is disposed.  Although this would work, it is quite a lot of code:

```
class WebResponseDisposingStream : Stream
{
    private readonly WebResponse response;
    private readonly Stream stream;

    public WebResponseDisposingStream(WebResponse response, Stream stream)
    {
        if (response == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("response");
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");

        this.response = response;
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        this.response.Close();
        this.stream.Close();
    }

    // override all the methods on stream and delegate the call to this.stream

    public override void Flush() { this.stream.Flush(); } // example delegation for Flush()
    // ... on and on for all the other members of Stream
}
```

Perhaps a better approach would be a continuation passing style where the code that uses the Stream is passed in as an delegate:

```
public void Load(string term, Action<Stream> action)
{
    var url = CreateSearchUrl(term);

    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        action(gzipStream);
    }
}
```

Now the caller simply passes in what should be done with the Stream.  In the following the length is printed to the console:

```
Load("test", stream => Console.WriteLine("Length=={0}", stream.Length));
```

One final note: In case you're not aware, HTTP has built-in support for compression.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) for more details.  The HttpWebRequest has built-in support for HTTP compression via the [AutomaticDecompression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression.aspx) property.  Using the HTTP compression basically makes the compression transparent to your code and also works better with HTTP tooling (browsers, fiddler, etc).